# BibTeX warning on extra title field

Tags: bibtex, warnings

I am using TeXnicCenter and MiKTeX for compiling. I have the following BibTeX entry:

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{cwang10,
author={Cong Wang and Cuirong Wang and Ying Yuan},
booktitle={Cyber-Enabled Distributed Computing and Knowledge Discovery (CyberC), 2010 International Conference on}, 
title={A High Performance, Low-Cost Network Architecture for Data Centers},
year={2010},
month={Oct.},
pages={284--287},
}
```

However I get a strange warning message that the above entry contains an "extra title field" and that BibTeX is ignoring said field. I have about 120 references.

Can you please help to fix this?

Comment: I used your entry to do a simple test and couldn't reproduce the problem. Please add to your question some minimal, yet *complete* document illustrating the problem.

Comment: Yes, just one reference does not make any problem. I have about 120 refereences and I doubt Bibtex is overflowing.

Comment: Please indicate which bibliography style file you use.

Comment: \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}  %plain
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,IEEEfull,MYFILE}

Comment: Again, with such short information the problem is not reproducible, thus not detectable. Are you sure the mentioned entry is the culprit? Can you at least add the exact (complete) error message you are getting?

Comment: Warning.. I am ignoring cwang10's extra "title" filed

Comment: I can send you the .bib if you want. Please let me know.

Comment: @Bill try using `bibtex8` instead of `bibtex`; i.e., process your document using `(pdf)latex + bibtex8 + (pdf)latex + (pdf)latex`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of the warning message

> Warning--I'm ignoring cwang10's extra "title" field

combined with the fact that you have *"about 120"* reference entries, I'm almost positive that you've run into BibTeX capacity issues. Quoting sections 2.4.2.1 and 2.4.2.2 of the [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) (sic!) manual:

> With a large `bib` file which contains several hundred entries, BibTeX
>   is very likely to run out of memory. [...] Unfortunately, traditional
>   BibTeX does not output a clear error message when it runs out of
>   memory but exposes a rather cryptical kind of faulty behavior. The
>   warning messages printed in this case look like this:
>
> ```
> Warning--I’m ignoring Jones1995’s extra "year" field
> --line 422 of file huge.bib
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> These warning messages could indeed indicate that the entry
>   `Jones1995` is faulty because it includes two year [...]
>   fields. If that is not the case and the `bib` file is fairly large,
>   this is most likely a capacity issue. What makes these warnings so
>   confusing is that they are not tied to a specific entry. If you remove
>   the allegedly faulty entry, a different one will trigger similar
>   warnings. This is one reason why switching to `bibtex8` [...] is
>   advisable.
>
> [...]
>
> [T]he capacity of [`bibtex8`] may be increased at run-time via
>   command-line switches and it also prints unambiguous error messages,
>   for example:
>
> ```
> 17289 fields:
> Sorry---you’ve exceeded BibTeX’s total number of fields 17250
> ```
>
> [...] The first thing you should always do is run `bibtex8` with the
>   `--wolfgang` switch. Don’t even bother trying anything else.

In other words, try to compile your document using

```
pdflatex
bibtex8 --wolfgang
pdflatex
pdflatex
```